# C++ Login System tips

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a secure auth system without using php/post any tips on how i can improve this. Maybe adding more checks?

```
if (IsWindows8OrGreater())
{
    cout << "Wrong Windows Version Contact an Admin" << endl;
    cout << "press any key then press enter to exit" << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
DWORD disk_serialINT;
GetVolumeInformation("C://", NULL, NULL, &disk_serialINT, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
TCHAR volumeName[MAX_PATH + 1] = { 0 };
TCHAR fileSystemName[MAX_PATH + 1] = { 0 };
DWORD serialNumber = 0;
DWORD maxComponentLen = 0;
DWORD fileSystemFlags = 0;
if (GetVolumeInformation(_T("C:\\"),volumeName,ARRAYSIZE(volumeName),& serialNumber, & maxComponentLen, & fileSystemFlags,  fileSystemName, ARRAYSIZE(fileSystemName))) 
{
        _tprintf(_T("Serial Number: %lu\n"), serialNumber);
        _tprintf(_T("fileSystemFlags Number: %lu\n"), fileSystemFlags);
}
if (Customer == serialNumber && CustomerFlags == fileSystemFlags)
{
    printf("Serial Number Matches required version\n");
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what that code has to do with logging in and in what way it is "secure"?

Comment: Eh, my bad it has nothing to do with that as I said its more of a authentication system and it's not secure at all but I am looking for ways to make it secure.